# Reverse Proxy - ProxyPass to HTTPS site

Tags: reverse-proxy, apache2

Im trying to config a reverse proxy server (Centos 7). The virtual host configuration as below:

```
 <VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName www.example2.com
  ServerAlias example2.com

  ProxyPass / https://keycdn.com/
  ProxyPassReverse / https://keycdn.com/

  SSLEngine on
  SSLProxyEngine on

  SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key

  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/example.com-error.log
  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/example.com-access.log combined
 </VirtualHost>
```

It is always do redirect to the actual URL rather than working as reverse-proxy, but working well for http site :

```
ProxyPass / http://example.com/
ProxyPassReverse / http://example.com/
```

Anybody can enlighten me on what should I do to able doing ProxyPass/ProxyPassReverse for HTTPS. Thanks.

**[EDIT]**

It always reply 301-Moved Permanently for https proxypass.

Comment: What do you see in /var/log/httpd/example.com-access.log when you try it?

Comment: It is normal log: 
S X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
192.168.1.129 - - [28/Apr/2018:16:13:59 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"

Comment: Please edit into the question the output of `curl -v https://www.example2.com`

Comment: So you got a redirect.  Not from this config, perhaps from keycdn.com?  Where did it send you to?  cfr the Location header.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille -  its redirect me to the https://keycdn.com. If I set the url to http://example.com, it rendering the http://example.com content but on the proxy ip.

Comment: @kubanczyk - i got connection refused when doing curl, but able to do browsing (if i set the passproxy to the http://example.com [http])

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
```

Comment: I got an error 451 response. What does its means?, Is it problems on the certs?

Comment: Where are you from?   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_451

Comment: You may need to provide the real domain names if you want help.